# Recursive relationship on a many to many table

Tags: sql, tree, firebird

I set up a many to many recursive table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PROD
(
IDPROD INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(3)
);

CREATE TABLE COMP
(
IDPARENT INT REFERENCES PROD(IDPROD),
IDCHILD INT REFERENCES PROD(IDPROD)
);

INSERT INTO PROD (IDPROD, NAME) VALUES (1, 'abc');
INSERT INTO PROD (IDPROD, NAME) VALUES (2, 'def');
INSERT INTO PROD (IDPROD, NAME) VALUES (3, 'ghi');
INSERT INTO PROD (IDPROD, NAME) VALUES (4, 'jkl');
INSERT INTO PROD (IDPROD, NAME) VALUES (5, 'mno');

INSERT INTO COMP (IDPARENT, IDCHILD) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO COMP (IDPARENT, IDCHILD) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO COMP (IDPARENT, IDCHILD) VALUES (4, 5);
```

With a recursivs CTE I can get all the children of a specific node from the second table.

```
WITH RECURSIVE TEST (IDPARENT, IDCHILD) AS
(SELECT P0.IDPARENT, P0.IDCHILD
FROM COMP AS P0
WHERE P0.IDPARENT = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT P1.IDPARENT, P1.IDCHILD
FROM COMP AS P1, TEST AS T
WHERE T.IDCHILD = P1.IDPARENT)

SELECT * FROM TEST
```

But I need a query that will give me the entire structure, not just for one node. Like in the classic adjacency list where you get all the root nodes where IDPARENT IS NULL and their children listed below. I use Firebird.

Comment: If you want to represent a tree, you don't need a n:m relation, a 1:n will do as all nodes have exactly one(!) parent (the root node has a NULL parent.

Comment: It has to be many to many in my case because many PROD (products) can have the same COMP (component).

Comment: ok, technically, it is not a tree then, but a directed graph.

Comment: In the example data it is a tiny forest of three tiny trees, just like the kind that Bob Ross liked to paint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Firebird, but this works in SQL Server, so is hopefully similar / enough to get you on track:

```
WITH TEST (IDRoot, IDPARENT, IDCHILD) AS
(

  SELECT P0.IDPROD, C0.IDParent, C0.IDCHILD
  FROM PROD AS P0
  left outer join COMP C0 on C0.IDParent = P0.IDPROD
  WHERE P0.IDProd not in (select IDChild from COMP)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T.IDRoot, C1.IDPARENT, C1.IDCHILD
  FROM COMP AS C1
  inner join TEST AS T on T.IDCHILD = C1.IDPARENT

)
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

Hope that helps.

SQL Fiddle Version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22f84/7

**Notes**

Includ a column to denote the root of the tree as well as parent/child - since there may be multiple trees if we're not specifying a particular root:

```
WITH TEST (IDRoot, IDPARENT, IDCHILD) AS
```

Treat any product which is not a child as a ROOT (i.e. first item in a tree).

```
WHERE P0.IDProd not in (select IDChild from COMP)
```

**EDIT: Answer to comments**

**Query on any node to see all of its relatives:**

The simple way to filter on any node would be to amend the above statement's `WHERE P0.IDProd not in (select IDChild from COMP)` with `WHERE P0.IDProd = IdImInterestedIn`.  However if you want to use the CTE for a view, then run queries over this static query you could use the code below - you can then filter on `IDProd` (`select * from test where IDProd = IdImInterestedIn`) to see that item's ancestors and descendants.

```
WITH TEST (IDProd, IDRelation, Generation) AS
(

  SELECT IDPROD
  , IDPROD
  , 0
  FROM PROD 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T.IDPROD
  , C.IdParent 
  , T.Generation - 1
  FROM TEST AS T
  inner join Comp as C 
  on C.IdChild = T.IDRelation
  where t.Generation <= 0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T.IDPROD
  , C.IdChild 
  , T.Generation + 1
  FROM TEST AS T
  inner join Comp as C 
  on C.IdParent = T.IDRelation
  where t.Generation >= 0

)
SELECT * 
FROM TEST
order by IDProd, Generation
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22f84/15

**See a root node's full tree in a single column**

```
WITH TEST (IDRoot, IDPARENT, IDCHILD, TREE) AS
(

  SELECT P0.IDPROD, C0.IDParent, C0.IDCHILD, cast(P0.IDPROD as nvarchar(max)) + coalesce(', ' + cast(C0.IDCHILD as nvarchar(max)),'')
  FROM PROD AS P0
  left outer join COMP C0 on C0.IDParent = P0.IDPROD
  WHERE P0.IDProd not in (select IDChild from COMP)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T.IDRoot, C1.IDPARENT, C1.IDCHILD, TREE + coalesce(', ' + cast(C1.IDCHILD as nvarchar(max)),'')
  FROM COMP AS C1
  inner join TEST AS T on T.IDCHILD = C1.IDPARENT

)
SELECT * 
FROM TEST 
order by IDRoot
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/22f84/19

**EDIT: Answer to Additional Comments**

```
with cte (tree_root_no, tree_row_no, relation_sort, relation_chart, Name, id, avoid_circular_ref) as
(
       select row_number() over (order by p.idprod) 
       , 1 
       , cast(row_number() over (order by p.idprod) as nvarchar(max)) 
       , cast('-' as nvarchar(max)) 
       , p.NAME 
       , p.IDPROD 
       , ',' + cast(p.IDPROD as nvarchar(max)) + ',' 
       from PROD p
       where p.IDPROD not in (select IDCHILD from COMP) --if it's nothing's child, it's a tree's root

       union all

       select cte.tree_root_no
       , cte.tree_row_no + 1
       , cte.relation_sort + cast(row_number() over (order by p.idprod) as nvarchar(max)) 
       , replace(relation_chart,'-','|') + ' -' 
       , p.NAME
       , p.IDPROD
       , cte.avoid_circular_ref + cast(p.IDPROD as nvarchar(max)) + ','
       from cte
       inner join COMP c on c.IDPARENT = cte.id
       inner join PROD p on p.IDPROD = c.IDCHILD
       where charindex(',' + cast(p.IDPROD as nvarchar(max)) + ',', cte.avoid_circular_ref) = 0
)
select tree_root_no, tree_row_no, relation_sort, relation_chart, id, name 
from cte 
order by tree_root_no, relation_sort
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4397f/9

**Update to show each path**

This one's a nasty hack, but the only way I could think of to solve your puzzle; this gives each path through the trees its own number:

```
;with inner_cte (parent, child, sequence, treePath) as (

    select null
    , p.IDPROD
    , 1
    , ',' + CAST(p.idprod as nvarchar(max)) + ','
    from @prod p
    where IDPROD not in 
    (
        select IDCHILD from @comp
    )

    union all

    select cte.child
    , c.IDCHILD
    , cte.sequence + 1
    , cte.treePath + CAST(c.IDCHILD as nvarchar(max)) + ','
    from inner_cte cte
    inner join @comp c on c.IDPARENT = cte.child

)
, outer_cte (id, value, pathNo, sequence, parent, treePath) as
(
    select icte.child, p.NAME, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by icte.child), icte.sequence, icte.parent, icte.treePath
    from inner_cte icte
    inner join @prod p on p.IDPROD = icte.child
    where icte.child not in (select coalesce(icte2.parent,-1) from inner_cte icte2) 

    union all

    select icte.child, p.NAME, octe.pathNo,icte.sequence, icte.parent, icte.treePath
    from outer_cte octe
    inner join inner_cte icte on icte.child = octe.parent and CHARINDEX(icte.treePath, octe.treePath) > 0
    inner join @prod p on p.IDPROD = icte.child

)
select id, value, pathNo
from outer_cte
order by pathNo, sequence
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a16e/1

Comment: It works, though with Firebird you have to add RECURSIVE after WITH, otherwise you get a "CTE 'TEST' has cyclic dependencies" error.

I do have two questions: given a node, how do I query all descendants and ancestors? And is it possible to list trees' structure on a column? For example if I add

INSERT INTO COMP (IDPARENT, IDCHILD) VALUES (1, 4);

can I have a column like this?

`1 -- root  
2 -- leaf  
1 -- root  
4  
5 -- leaf  
3 -- root  
4  
5 -- leaf  `

Visual

http://postimg.org/image/j6z5s86v3/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. I only wish one day I'll have that kind of SQL skill. Regarding my second question, I was thinking about something else. Each number was meant to be a row in a column, but stackoverflow formatted the output. That's how I found you can't have line breaks in comments. Just a happy accident, I guess :) What I want is to put the trees on the same column with each node on a separate row. I updated the image. http://postimg.org/image/57fwkuf5r/

Comment: Think I've got a solution for you - but that's a really tricky one, so the code's a bit hacky: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a16e/1

Comment: No time to test it with Firebird atm, but thank you for the input, it's been helpful. Man, I'd love to see more implementations like CONNECT BY from Oracle, these recursive CTEs are giving me headaches.